# Javascript: String concatenation in object constructor

Tags: javascript, string-concatenation

Been trying to create a JavaScript object member that always contains a common string.  Whenever I create a new object, instead of concatenating the string, it overwrites it with the passed value on creation.  If it matters (I don't think it does) the string contains numbers.  Par example:

```
function myObj(strToConcat){
    this.combinedString = "Hello " + strToConcat, /* have used + and .concat() without success */
}

var newObj = new myObj("1.2.3");
console.log(newObj.combinedString); /* says "1.2.3", the leading "Hello " is absent */
```

Can't seem to get this to concatenate the strings.

EDIT: I apologize, the error was outside the code that I thought responsible.  Disregard please.  My apologies.

Comment: Your example is pretty broken and does not output what you claim it to output. You have a syntax error and access the wrong variable. If you fix both it works: http://jsfiddle.net/CS2VD/. No idea how you would get `"1.2.3"` though.

Answer (score 2):

You have error in your reference

```
console.log(myObj.combinedString);
```

should be

```
console.log(newObj.combinedString);
```

Comment: Argh, that's a typo.  That's not what my code says. Sorry for misleading

Comment: also this is an error `this.combinedString = "Hello " + strToConcat,` - remove the comma at the end and put semicolon

Comment: If the OP really had `console.log(myObj.combinedString);` in their code, it would output `undefined` though, not `"1.2.3"`. So, while this is a problem in the posted code, it's unlikely the problem for the OP's actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Running your code gives me `SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`. Replace the `,` at the end of the second line with a `;` and I get the expected result of "Hello 1.2.3".

Comment: If this error was in the OP's actual code, he would never get the output `"1.2.3"` though.

Comment: I know, we can only debug what is posted though. It would have been quite helpful if the actual code had been posted :)